# How to select rows with same values in one column but all must be different between each other in another column

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone i will try to be as specific and precise as possible.

I was looking around for answer to my problem and in mean time i made 2 tables

In first table i have names of Companies and their id-s.

In second table i have names of Employees,their id-s,the cities in which they live,and idK-s(its supposed to match id id-s from previous table) of Companies they work in.

I am supposed to select names of Companies that have at least four(3 or more) employees living in different cities compared to each other.

In order for things to be more clear i am going to give an example:

table1:

```
id  name

1   Company1
2   Company2
3   Company3
4   Company4
5   Company5
6   Company6
```

table2:

```
id  name     city        idK

1   EMP1     city1       1
2   EMP2     city2       1
3   EMP3     city3       1
4   EMP4     city4       1

5   EMP5     city1       2
6   EMP6     city2       2
7   EMP7     city3       2

8   EMP8     city1       3
9   EMP9     city2       3
10  EMP10    city3       3

11  EMP11    city1       4
12  EMP12    city2       4
13  EMP13    city3       4
14  EMP14    city4       4
15  EMP15    city5       4

16  EMP16    city1       5
17  EMP17    city2       5
18  EMP18    city1       5
19  EMP19    city3       5
20  EMP20    city3       5   
21  EMP21    city2       5

22  EMP22    city1       6
23  EMP23    city8       6
24  EMP24    city1       6
25  EMP25    city15      6
```

I made spaces so it is easier to see.
So in idK=1 we have four employees and all are from different city compared to each other so Company1 should be in results.

idK=2 and idK=3 have under four employees in general so Company2 and Company3 are out.

idK=4 is good same reasons as idK=1 but idK=5 and idK=6 are out because while they have four or more employees they are not from different cities compared to each other.

I found similar problems as mine and some solutions but none were good enough for me or i just couldn't make them work so i would be very grateful if someone could explain to me what to do in this situation.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work here.

```
select t1.name from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t2.idK = t1.id
group by t2.idk,t1.name
having count(distinct city) > 3
```

This is the data I used to test on db-fiddle.

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (id int, name varchar(100), city varchar(100), idK int);


INSERT INTO table2 (id,name,city,idK)
VALUES (1,'EMP1','city1',1),
(2,'EMP2','city2',1),
(3,'EMP3','city3',1),
(4,'EMP4','city4',1),
(5,'EMP5','city1',2),
(6,'EMP6','city2',2),
(7,'EMP7','city3',2),
(8,'EMP8','city1',3),
(9,'EMP9','city2',3),
(10,'EMP10','city3',3),
(11,'EMP11','city1',4),
(12,'EMP12','city2',4),
(13,'EMP13','city3',4),
(14,'EMP14','city4',4),
(15,'EMP15','city5',4),
(16,'EMP16','city1',5),
(17,'EMP17','city2',5),
(18,'EMP18','city1',5),
(19,'EMP19','city3',5),
(20,'EMP20','city3',5), 
(21,'EMP21','city2',5),

(22,'EMP22','city1',6),
(23,'EMP23','city8',6),
(24,'EMP24','city1',6),
(25,'EMP25','city15',6);


Create TABLE table1 (id int,name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO table1 (id,name)
VALUES (1,'Company1'),
(2,'Company2'),
(3,'Company3'),
(4,'Company4'),
(5,'Company5'),
(6,'Company6');
```

Comment: You are completely correct and when i create these tables and insert into them the way you did it works but i can't make it work for my already existing tables and i can't figure out the reason the data type is the same.
Anyway thank you very much this works just fine i will just figure out what is going on on my existing tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use count(DISTINCT columnname) to get the number of unique values in a column.

```
SELECT
    c.`name`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.`city`) as `Num Cities`
FROM `companies` c
JOIN `employees` e
ON c.`id` = e.`idK`
WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT e.`city`) > 3
GROUP BY c.`name`
ORDER BY c.`name`
```

Comment: I need to replace WHERE with HAVING and move GROUP BY above it in order for code to execute and after i do that i get no results
(i am working in phpmyadmin from localhost...xampp)
I am not sure if that is some problem considering you used WHERE

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is what you are looking for

```
select idk
  from table2
 group by idk
having count(distinct city) > 3
```

Comment: Well in general terms it seems correct but it is not giving me any results